# How to switch sql worksheet display in oracle sql developer 3.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In the sql worksheet of oracle sql developer when you press the keys `ctrl + [up/down]arrow` the worksheet switch into a single sql statmenet navigation. It breaks your script into individual statements and let's you navigate between them.

How can i switch back to the original one long script ?

I can't seem to find it.

**EDIT:**
and how can i completely cancel this option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ctrl-up` and `ctrl-down` navigate your query history in SQL Worksheet, at least by default. That doesn't sound quite like what you're seeing, but possibly you're going back through old versions of partial statements that you've now combined in a single script, in which case you can just `ctrl-up` until you get back to the current state (though it only seems to keep things you've executed, so if you change something and then hit `ctrl-down` before running, I think your changes are gone...).

I don't think you can disable that behaviour, but you can make it harder to trigger by accident, if that is what's happening. From the Tools->Preferences->Shortcut Keys option, search for `ctrl-down`, and highlight the entry for category 'Other'. Click in the 'new shortcut' area at the bottom and type a more obscure key combination (that isn't already used) and click 'Assign'. Repeat for `ctrl-up`.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I also though that it navigates between versions of the page (same behavior in plsql developer) but i still cant reach the original script. As you suggested , i disabled the keyboard shortcuts. - good enough solution. The caption, btw. is "SQL history : append from Next / Previous".

Comment: at least since 4.0.2.15 it is possible to remove these shortcuts

Answer (score 6):

Using "Ctrl-Z" to go backwards also gets you there, but it does it one step at a time (e.g. Ctrl-Down 5 times requires 5 corresponding "undo" actions to take you back).

Comment: I know this is rather old, but this answers the first part of the question, "How can i switch back..." and the accepted answer seems to (incorrectly in my experience) indicate that your unsaved work is lost when you accidentally press ctrl-down. If you just want to undo ctrl-down, then ctrl-z is right.